# Python multiprocessing log_to_stderr duplicated on Windows

Tags: python, windows, logging, duplicates, multiprocessing

I'm following the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#logging) for logging with multiprocessing, but I am seeing two logs created by the worker in each subprocess. Am I making a dumb mistake somewhere?

**Environment**:

Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:25:24) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

**Code (edited to fix scope issue recommended by @georgexsh)**:

```
import logging
import multiprocessing


logger = multiprocessing.log_to_stderr(logging.INFO)


def test(i):
    logger.info(f'worker processing {i}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        metrics = pool.map(test, range(20))
```

**Logging output:**

```
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-2] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-2] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-2] worker processing 0
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-3] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-3] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-2] worker processing 0
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-3] worker processing 1
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-2] worker processing 2
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-6] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-3] worker processing 1
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-4] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-2] worker processing 2
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-5] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-7] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] worker processing 3
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-6] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-3] worker processing 4
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-4] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-2] worker processing 5
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-5] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-7] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] worker processing 3
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-6] worker processing 6
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-3] worker processing 4
...
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-5] worker processing 16
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-2] worker processing 12
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-7] worker processing 17
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] worker processing 18
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-6] worker processing 13
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-3] worker processing 19
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-8] worker processing 14
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-4] worker processing 15
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-5] worker processing 16
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-7] worker processing 17
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] worker processing 18
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-3] worker processing 19
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-2] process shutting down
[INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-6] process shutting down
[INFO/MainProcess] process shutting down
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

move `logger = multiprocessing.log_to_stderr()` to global scope, not inside worker function. to make sure it only called once. because each time `log_to_stderr` gets called, [it will add a new handler to the logger](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.1/Lib/multiprocessing/util.py#L87-L103):

```
def test(i):
    logger.info('worker processing %s', i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger = multiprocessing.log_to_stderr(logging.INFO)
```

note that under windows, as there is no `fork()`, [the whole module get executed again](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.1/Lib/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_win32.py#L43-L67) when the child process is created to reconstruct context, you could initialize logger with [`Pool`'s `initializer`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.1/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#L104-L105), it runs only once pre-child process:

```
logger = None

def test(i):
    logger.info('worker processing %s', i)

def initializer(level):
    global logger
    logger = multiprocessing.log_to_stderr(level)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4, initializer=initializer, initargs=(logging.INFO,))
    metrics = pool.map(test, range(20))
```

Comment: Thanks for catching the scope issue! This seems to work when I run the code on Linux, but I'm still seeing duplicate logs (now only two per subprocess) on Windows.

Comment: @atm got it, python use a different fork method in windows, i will revise later.